# MPAndroidchart No chart Data available

Tags: charts, dataset, mpandroidchart

I am having problems with MPAndroidChart.
I am adding temperature and Humidity Data to the chart, but it always displays "no chart Data available".
Anybody here who can see where my bug is?
I would be super grateful!

```
//Create Data

                //set size of data
                int size = list.size();
                if (size > 24){ size = 24;}

                //create lists form temp and hum
                ArrayList<Entry> temps = new ArrayList<Entry>();
                ArrayList<Entry> hums = new ArrayList<Entry>();


                //fill list temp with values
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                    Entry value = new Entry(Math.round(list.get(list.size()-size + i).temp), (size-i));
                    temps.add(value);
                }

                //fill list hum with values
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                    Entry value = new Entry(Math.round(list.get(list.size()-size + i).hum), (size-i));
                    hums.add(value);
                }

                //other views on screen
                date.setText(dateString);
                time.setText(timeString);
                temp.setText(tempString);
                hum.setText(humString);


                //adding Data and description to array
                LineDataSet setTemp = new LineDataSet(temps, "Temperature");
                setTemp.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
                LineDataSet setHum = new LineDataSet(hums, "Humidity");
                setHum.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

                //adding Arrays to DataSet
                ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
                dataSets.add(setTemp);
                dataSets.add(setHum);
                ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();

                //Adding x values of range size
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
                    xVals.add(String.valueOf(i));
                }

                //add Data and create chart
                LineData data = new LineData(xVals, dataSets);
                chart.setData(data);
                chart.invalidate();

            }
        });
```

Comment: Try changing `(size-i)` to `i` in the `Entry` constructor. Let me know if that changes anything.

Comment: Hello Philipp,
Thanks for taking a look at my problem. Sadly that did not resolve the problem. I must be using the code wrong somewhere.

Comment: My best guess is that it has someting to do with your `size` variable. Have you tried removing it and see what happens?

Comment: Hey which version of MpAndroidchart are you using. I am using 2.1.5 and am not able to import ILineDataSet

Answer (score 1):

You need to call after you set the data:

```
 chart.invalidate();
```

to refresh the chart.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this post long time. The only thing I can think about is this line:

```
Math.round(list.get(list.size()-size + i).hum
```

What's that `.hum` ? Could it generate an unsupported type for Entry?
The resolution to this issue intrigues me so much since Mr. Phil J. did not found the answer yet.