# iOS Charts (MPAndroidChart) using multiple data sets always shows "No chart data available"

Tags: swift, charts, mpandroidchart

None of the solutions, in the multiple SO questions, for "No chart data available" is able to remove/modify the message:

[MPAndroidchart No chart Data available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241378/mpandroidchart-no-chart-data-available)

[How to change the No Data message using iOS Charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65497368/how-to-change-the-no-data-message-using-ios-charts)

[collection view presentation of graph: "no chart data available" for Charts cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66890586/collection-view-presentation-of-graph-no-chart-data-available-for-charts-coco)

The chart displays the data correctly but also displays the message "No chart data available". It really just seems like a bug for the chart to have data but show this message.

The only difference between the other SO questions and my problem is that I'm setting the data with `dataSets` instead of `dataSet` viz. `LineChartData(dataSets: data_sets)`. Seeing this difference I tried creating the LineChart view with a dummy LineChartData initialized with `dataSet`, before running `updateChartData()`, but this didn't help either.

I don't see a way to initialize the LineChartView with the data, the closest I've seen to potentially doing this [is shown on this site](https://medium.com/@zzzzbh/plotting-in-ios-using-charts-framework-with-swiftui-222034a2bea6)

```
@IBOutlet weak var chartview_box: UIView!
var chartview: LineChartView 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    chartview = LineChartView()
    chartview.noDataText = "test"
    chartview.noDataTextColor = UIColor(hue: 0, saturation: 0, brightness: 0, alpha: 0)
    setChartOptions()
    updateChartData()
}

func updateChartData() {
    var data_sets: Array<LineChartDataSet> = []
    for frame in frames! {
        ... code setting x and y
        let entry = ChartDataEntry(x: x, y: y)
        let data_set = LineChartDataSet(entries: [entry])
        data_sets.append(data_set)
    }
    let data = LineChartData(dataSets: data_sets)
    chartview.data = data
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with accidentally leaving a parent container as LineChartView when it should be UIView, so the parent view "behind" the chart was also a chart and displaying the message.